# Передача цифр из одного input в другой

Tags: jquery, javascript

Проблема такая- есть 3 инпута (z1,z2,z3) ввожу в z1 вручную цифры - всё передаётся отлично, но к z1 прикреплён скролл, так вот если менять цифры скролом, то тогда цифры не передаются - что делать?

```
    $(function(){
    $("#z1").keyup(function(event){
        $("#z2").val($("#z1").val());                
    });
     $("#z1").keyup(function(event){
        $("#z3").val($("#z1").val());                
    });
});
```

сделал так,

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('change click keyup','#z1',function(event) {
        $("#z2").val($("#z1").val());                
    });
    $(document).on('change click keyup','#z1',function(event) {
        $("#z3").val($("#z1").val());                
    });
});
```

но у меня в z2 стоит такой мини фильтр - и после такой конструкции он перестаёт работать

```
<input type="text" id="z2" class="textbox range" onblur="document.getElementById('flash').innerHTML = (this.value > 500000 ? '<ul>Html код ')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

keyup не сработает если вы скриптом что то напишете в инпут. В этом случае сработает change, то есть вам нужно два события перехватывать, либо возбудить keyup вручную, что не очень правильно

Comment: т.е. keyup заменить на change? Можно чуть подробнее?

Comment: Если просто заменить, то по вводу символа в поле не будет ничего происходить. Change срабатывает в случае если val изменился и курсор не в поле, либо произошел blur. То есть вам нужно вашу функцию повесить на оба события.

Вообще почитайте хотя бы документацию jquery на тему событий, там интересно

Comment: я ошибся у меня не blur стоит а onchange